# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library /usr/local/xuggler/lib/libxuggle-xuggler.so.3.4.1012 already loaded in another classloader

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, xuggle

I successfully introduced  **xuggle** in my tomcat environment and it worked perfectly. 
Than something happens , and from that moment on, any time my thumbnail generator is called ( is the class that uses xuggle the most) i got the 
`*java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library /usr/local/xuggler/lib/libxuggle-xuggler.so.3.4.1012 already loaded in another classloader*` exception.
The only way I have to fix it is by restarting tomcat.
Since I can't reproduce the error nor on my laptop, I really appreciate a little help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens probably because you have the Xuggler Jars in a webapp lib directory, and it needs to be at the CATALINA_ROOT directory.  See the [Xuggler FAQ](http://wiki.xuggle.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#I_get_an_.22UnsatisfiedLinkError.22_when_I_run_Xuggler-based_Applications_in_Tomcat) for details.  Stop tomcat, move the Xuggler jar files to the ${CATALINA_HOME}/shared/lib directory and restart tomcat and all should be OK.

Comment: I also had to improve my pom.xml by setting the scope of the dependency as provided, then it worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

If you can't reproduce the same problem on other devices, try to check if your system classpath has entry for this specific jar file because in usual tomcat configuration, system classpath is added along-with lib jar files.